# Entity owned by more than one entity

Tags: java, jpa, constraints, eclipselink

consider the following relation ship:

Entity A have a bidirectional  one to many relation with entity B.
Entity A have a unidirectional one to one relation with entity C.
Entity C have a bidirectional  one to many relation with entity D.
Entity B have a bidirectional  one to many relation with entity D.

then

```
    A a =new A();
    B b =new B();
    C c =new C();
    D d =new D();

    List<B> bs=new ArrayList<>();
    bs.add(b);
    a.setBs(bs);
    b.setA(a);

    a.setC(c);
    List<D> ds=new ArrayList<>();
    ds.add(d);
    b.setDs(ds);
    d.setB(b);

   c.setDs(ds);
   d.setC(c);
```

all relation have cascade merge

```
em.merge(a);
```

when calling merge psql(PostgreSQL exception raised) stating that inserting d is not possible since b doesn't exist (constraint violation) .
it seems that **a** persisted/inserted than **c** persisted/inserted than eclipse link trying to inserting **d** while **b** still not inserted.
how to solve such problem knowing that all this must happen withing the same transaction.

Comment: You could try merging `b` instead of `a`. The Entity Manager should be able to traverse an Entity tree from any point. It doesn't have to be 'top down'. Anyway, shouldn't it be `em.persist` if you are creating `a`?

Comment: the facade used for saving A , b sometimes might not found yet a,c,d found. merge  take care of both insert and update.

Comment: Something else is happening, as I expect EclipseLink to insert C, A, B and then D unless the mappings are different then described.  Is there anyway to delay the constraint processing until after the transaction?  Turn on EclipseLink logging to finest, create a schema without constraints, and see what SQL statements are issued to verify the exact order it tries for all the inserts as it might help determine what is being missed.  Inserts are issued in a process separate from the merge/persist relationship traversal, and is done on per class.  So all Cs should be inserted, then all As etc.